# setuptools, install_requires does not fetch from pip

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Let's say you are behind a firewall and a proxy and don't have internet
access. That way you can't access PyPi public repository.

Add in your /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.0 pypi.python.org.
```

In your company you have a JFrog artifactory which serves pypi packages
by caching pypi.python.org but you only have access to this web server.

So If you have a project which has the following configuration:

1. `tests_require = [ 'pytest', 'pytest-runner' ]`
2. `install_requires = [ 'pyyaml' ]`
3. `requirements.text` has only a reference to `pyyaml`

and you have configured `~/.pip/pip.conf` to access this local JFrog 
artifactory,

As so this project can never be functional as in `requirements.text` you
can fetch pyyaml from local jfrog, but you can never fetch `pyttest` since
it requires access to pypi.python.org.

Keep in mind that test requirements should not be in requirements.text;
somebody may need to package this application with `PEX`.

Why isn't setuptools using `pip` to fetch dependencies?

Why all this redundancy and complexity? In this context I don't understand how the different role of `install_requires` and `pip freeze` is functional.

I need to work only with a local pypi index and declare my requirements once, (test or deployment requirements).

Note:
Using pip's internal api to unify setuptools:install_requires and requirements.text is not a real solution